# How to debug native dll dllmain in visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, dll

I am using visual studio 2010 team system, I have two projects in the solution both compiled in c:

1. DLL project containing DLL main and an exported function
2. console project that loads this DLL using dynmaic loading (LoadLibrary)

I want to be able to debug the DLLmain function called by the LoadLibrary, how is that possible ?

Comment: [How to: Debug Native DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c91k1xcf.aspx)

Comment: @CodyGray
I tried it, the break point becomes empty circle when i start debugging, although i tried both ways debugging from the exe project and debugging from dll project

Comment: I created New projects and it worked, thanks anyway.

Comment: The answer from Edgar is a bit late but it _is_ correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your breakpoint was "neglected" because you were debugging an old build.

To avoid this issue allways rebuild your solution,  or at least the project you'll like to debug.

Answer (score 0):

*to sum this up for others:*

Follow this MS [How to: Debug Native DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/how-to-debug-native-dlls?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN).

All you then have to do is **place a breakpoint in your `DllMain`**.

When you start debugging with the calling EXE, it is not enough to step-in when reaching `LoadLibrary()`.
However it is possible to step-in when calling a DLL function which address was retrieved using `GetProcAddress()`.

Make sure you **place the appropriate PDB file next to the DLL** to be loaded.

[Make sure your **build binaries are up-to-date**, as Edgar pointed out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19081052/16049096).